# Visual Studio 2012 app.config is not updated when settings tab changes

Tags: visual-studio, app-config, configuration-files

It seems that i cant make app.config get the new settings value when i change them from the project properties settings tab.

I tried cleaning up the project and recompiling but that doesn't help.

the [app.exe].config file is generated in the compile output path but with the values of the app.config which are NOT the ones i am putting in every compilation in settings tab of project properties within VS2012...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use application Setting ... It worked on VS 2005

For example:

Create a New Setting: **Project menu-> Properties -> Settings ->create a setting as below**

```
Name         Type               Scope      Value
myLoc   System.Drawing.Point    User       2;2
```

Applied to app

Read Settings when Form_Load

```
Button1.Location = My.Settings.myLoc
```

Change and save Settings

```
My.Settings.myLoc = Button1.Location
My.Settings.Save()
```